# Nutanix VM migration to Azure - VM creation timed out

Tags: azure, migration, virtual-machine, azure-vm, nutanix

In the process of Nuntanix Virtual Machine migration to Azure, I had copied ral-rdmbuild-02 copy.ova file into a windows machine and extracted to get .vmdk and .mf. From the extracted file the .vhd file was created, later it was resized on a ubuntu to meet 1MB requirement.

Subsequently, the .vhd was copied to azure and attempted to create a vm to face the following error. Could someone can help me to overcome this issue.

*{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"OSProvisioningTimedOut","message":"OS Provisioning for VM '' did not finish in the allotted time. The VM may still finish provisioning successfully. Please check provisioning state later. Also, make sure the image has been properly prepared (generalized).\r\n * Instructions for Windows: https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-upload-image/ \r\n * Instructions for Linux: https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-capture-image/ \r\n * If you are deploying more than 20 Virtual Machines concurrently, consider moving your custom image to shared image gallery. Please refer to https://aka.ms/movetosig for the same."}]}*

Comment: It’s hard to say what’s happening without access to `boot` logs. I don’t see you installing `waagent` on the image you exported to azure. This agent is used heavily during VM provisioning. Also, enable boot logs by enabling boot diagnostics & check whether you can access serial console & boot logs & share them here

Comment: While working to enable boot diagnostics, I found the VM failed to provisioning (in the instance view, the ProvisioningState=failed). Also no extension were installed/configured. Could you please let me know what are the other details I must check to understand the cause for failure.

Comment: Hey @AmalorpavadossKulandaisamy had it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

•   Please check whether the Nutanix VM hard disk is configured as a dynamic disk or not because dynamic disks don’t work with Azure, and they can’t be migrated. Also, the image of the Nutanix VM may not be prepared correctly, thus would suggest you recreate the image of the Nutanix VM and try migrating it to Azure once again.

•   To convert the dynamic disk to fixed type of virtual disk, kindly refer to the below documentation link that guides to use the appropriate command for converting the same: -

```
Convert-VHD -Path c:\test\child1vhdx.vhdx -DestinationPath c:\test\child1vhd.vhd -VHDType Fixed
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/convert-vhd?view=windowsserver2019-ps

•   Also, based on the error message that you are encountering, the OS deployment might have also failed from the Portal side as it was unable to pass on some of the required parameters which is why you got **‘TimeOut’** message. The VM also didn’t finish the deployment correctly. I would recommend **trying stop(deallocate) and start the VM** and see if that resolves the issue.

I would recommend **you delete the VM and its related resources if created and take a snapshot of the OS disk**, create a disk from the snapshot and then create the machine from that disk. Please refer to the link below for creating a VM from a **‘VHD’** by using the Azure portal: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/create-upload-centos

•   Finally, to generalize the VM and execute **‘sysprep’** on a VM to take its correct reference image such that it can be successfully migrated to another environment, please refer to the below link that explains the correct steps to perform for generalizing the VM: -

https://portal.nutanix.com/page/documents/details?targetId=Web-Console-Guide-Prism-v6_1:wc-windows-vm-customize-with-sysprep-clone-vm-wc-t.html